# Oracle DB Connectivity issue with Java Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, connection, oracle11g

Actually I am trying to call queryForInt() method but it displays NULL exception. When I acces the dB with same credential using Following Code:

----------------This is Working-----------------------

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
dataSource.setUsername("userName");
dataSource.setPassword("pwd");
```

------ In Bean -----------------(This is not working)

```
<!-- DAOS -->
<bean id="ProductDAO" class="br.edeploy.voive.dao.ProductDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

---------On ProductDAO Class --------------(Exception is thrown here when I use Spring method)

```
try
{
  int i = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForInt("Select * from ERP_PRODUCT", "");
}
catch(DataAccessException dax)
{
  throw new Exception("Error: "+dax.getMessage());
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace? There is something I don't get: You build your datasource doing `DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();` but you inject it in your `productDAO` using a reference to `datasource`. It seems obvious that the datasource you are building in the first snippet is not the same instance than the one you  inject in the second snippet. But maybe if we see more of your configuration we will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Spring jdbcTemplate.queryForInt() support following parameters

```
 int    queryForInt(String sql) 
          Execute a query that results in an int value, given static SQL.

 int    queryForInt(String sql, Object[] args) 
          Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL and a list of arguments to bind to the query, resulting in an int value.

 int    queryForInt(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes) 
          Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL and a list of arguments to bind to the query, resulting in an int value.
```

You pass argument for the parameters, not sure why are you using second method and not the first method (when you don't need to pass parameters)

**EDIT**
The way to use queryForInt() is :

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMER";

int total = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql);
```

Looking at your code, looks like you need to use `queryForObject()`

```
String sql = "SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = ?";

String name = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
            sql, new Object[] { custId }, String.class);
```

Comment: Hi, Actually I tried that earlier but didn't work. Can you tell me how to call this method [of ProductDAO class named "GetProduct()"] in my Servlet Class?